# Simple turn-based game fight system

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java. I am making a basic turn-based game, but I have problems with the fight system. I attack the randomly selected enemy with the chosen weapon until it dies, however I can't figure out how to decrease my HP.

I tried the following method in the Character class:

```
public void attack(int damageAmount, int myHealth) {
    if (damageAmount >= this.health || myHealth<=0) {
        this.health = 0;
        System.out.println( this.name + " is dead!");
        this.dead = true;
    } else {
        this.health -= damageAmount;
        System.out.println("The remaining life of " + this.name + " is: " + this.health);
        player.setHealth(myHealth-this.damage);
        System.out.println("Your remaining HP: "+ myHealth);
```

It doesn't work, because the " player.setHealth()" is not reachable in the Character class.

How could I solve this? Should I make another class for the fight system? 
Also, canI make my code simplier by using inheritance or interfaces?

Thanks in advance guys!

**MAIN CLASS**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static int size = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myHealth = 1000;
        int myDamage = 5;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Character zombie = new Character("Zombie", 500, 10);
        Character wolf = new Character("Wolf", 200, 30);
        Character dragon = new Character("Dragon", 1000, 200);
        Character bigDragon = new Character("Big Dragon", 2000, 400);
        Character vampire = new Character("Vampire", 1000, 250);
        ArrayList<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<>();
        characterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                zombie,
                wolf,
                dragon,
                bigDragon,
                vampire
        ));
        Weapon fist = new Weapon("Fist", 5);
        Weapon sword = new Weapon("Sword", 50);
        Weapon bow = new Weapon("Bow", 40);
        Weapon crossBow = new Weapon("Crossbow", 35);
        Weapon revolver = new Weapon("Revolver", 100);
        ArrayList<Weapon> weaponList = new ArrayList<>();
        weaponList.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                fist,
                sword,
                bow,
                crossBow,
                revolver
        ));
        size = characterList.size();
        int whichCharacter = random();
        for (int i = 0; i < characterList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". character: " + characterList.get(random()).getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Your name!");
        String myName = sc.nextLine();
        Character player = new Character(myName, 1000, myDamage);
        System.out.println("Your name: " + myName);
        System.out.println("Your HP: " + myHealth);
        System.out.println("Your attack power: " + myDamage);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You were attacked by a(n):");
        System.out.println("Name: " + characterList.get(whichCharacter).getName());
        System.out.println("HP: " + characterList.get(whichCharacter).getHealth());
        System.out.println("Attack power: " + characterList.get(whichCharacter).getDamage());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You attack with...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1. fist");
        System.out.println("2. sword");
        System.out.println("3. bow");
        System.out.println("4. crossbow");
        System.out.println("5. revolver");
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        while (!characterList.get(whichCharacter).isDead()) {
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    myDamage = 5;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myDamage = sword.getWeaponDamage();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    myDamage = bow.getWeaponDamage();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    myDamage = crossBow.getWeaponDamage();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    myDamage = revolver.getWeaponDamage();
                    break;
                default:
                    myDamage = 5;
            }


            while (!characterList.get(whichCharacter).isDead()) {
                characterList.get(whichCharacter).attack(myDamage, myHealth);
                //characterList.get(whichCharacter).attack(characterList.get(whichCharacter).getDamage(), player.getHealth());
            }

        }

}
    public static int random() {
        int szam = (int) (Math.random() * size);
        return szam;
    }
}
```

**CHARACTER CLASS**

```
package com.company;

/**
 * Created by Norbi on 2017.04.29..
 */
public class Character {
    private String name;
    private int health;
    private int damage;
    private boolean dead = false;

    public boolean isDead() {
        return dead;
    }

    public void setDead(boolean dead) {
        this.dead = dead;
    }

    public Character(boolean dead) {
        this.dead = dead;
    }

    public Character(String name, int health, int damage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }

    public void setDamage(int damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
    }


    public void attack(int damageAmount, int myHealth) {
        if (damageAmount >= this.health || myHealth<=0) {
           // this.health = 0;
            System.out.println(this.name + " is dead!");
            this.dead = true;
        } else {
            this.health -= damageAmount;

            System.out.println("The remaining life of " + this.name + " is: " + this.health);

            System.out.println("Your remaining HP: "+ myHealth);


        }


}}
```

**WEAPON CLASS**

```
package com.company;

/**
 * Created by Norbi on 2017.04.29..
 */
public class Weapon {
    private String name;
    private int weaponDamage;

    public Weapon(String name, int weaponDamage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weaponDamage = weaponDamage;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getWeaponDamage() {
        return weaponDamage;
    }

    public void setWeaponDamage(int weaponDamage) {
        this.weaponDamage = weaponDamage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `player` come from in the attack method you tried? Seems as if the "opponent" that attacks is missing in the list of parameters...

Comment: I tried the following in the attack method, but it's not working:

`   player.setHealth(myHealth-this.damage);`

Comment: you wrote that already at the beginning of your question, but you use `player.setHealth(myHealth - this.damage` - and I cannot see, which type is `player` nor where it comes from in that piece of code.

Comment: Sorry, just found it - you create it in the main method.
Try to add a parameter of type `Character` to the attack method - but please, call it "otherPlayer" or something like that ;-)

Comment: player is an object of my Main class, but I suppose I can't use it in the Character class. 
Sorry, I know that I am completely noob, thanks for helping me!

Comment: Each `Character` has a health attribute, so you shouldn't be passing in the health value to the attack method. You should just use the health attribute already defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in looping logic, I hope it would help :

```
       while (!characterList.get(whichCharacter).isDead() && !player.isDead()) {
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    myDamage = 5;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myDamage = sword.getWeaponDamage();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    myDamage = bow.getWeaponDamage();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    myDamage = crossBow.getWeaponDamage();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    myDamage = revolver.getWeaponDamage();
                    break;
                default:
                    myDamage = 5;
            }

            while (!characterList.get(whichCharacter).isDead() && !player.isDead()) {
                characterList.get(whichCharacter).attack(myDamage, myHealth);
                player.attack(characterList.get(whichCharacter).getDamage(), player.getHealth());
                //characterList.get(whichCharacter).attack(characterList.get(whichCharacter).getDamage(), player.getHealth());
            }

        }
```

Comment: My pleasure @Norbi :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need an instance of `player` to call its methods, you could pass it as an input parameter, for example you could call the `attack` method like this:

```
characterList.get(whichCharacter).attack(player);
```

and modify it like this (simply replacing `damageAmount` and `myHealth` with the corresponding methods from `Character`):

```
public void attack(Character characterAttacked) {
    if (characterAttacked.getDamage() >= this.health || characterAttacked.getHealth() <= 0) {
        this.health = 0;
        System.out.println( this.name + " is dead!");
        this.dead = true;
    } else {
        this.health -= characterAttacked.getDamage();
        System.out.println("The remaining life of " + this.name + " is: " + this.health);
        characterAttacked.setHealth(characterAttacked.getHealth() - this.damage);
        System.out.println("Your remaining HP: "+ characterAttacked.getHealth());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to prepare an answer with a suggestion for a working attack method I found out, that your attack method does not work for me.

So here some general suggestions to improve your code:

- Use an instance of Character for the player too.
- pass that instance to the attack method.
- Improve the use of lists (I will add an example below.)
- use a Map with the user entered number as key instead of the switch statement.

Improved use of lists:

```java
// Use the generic interface List instead of implementation class.
// You don't need extra ArrayList, just use the result of Arrays.asList
//  - if you don't need to change the list afterwards.
List<Character> characterList = 
    Arrays.asList(
      zombie, 
      wolf, 
      dragon, 
      bigDragon, 
      vampire);
```

Use Map for weapons:

```java
Map<Integer, Weapon> weapons = new HashMap<>();
weapons.put(1, fist);
weapons.put(2, sword);
// and so on - you get the idea
while (!characterList.get(whichCharacter).isDead() && !player.isDead()) {
  Weapon weapon = weapons.get(choice);
  if (null == weapon) {
    weapon = fist;
  }
  myDamage = weapon.getDamage();
  // and here you can continue your code
}
```

Hope that above suggestions also help you a bit further.

Comment: `weapon = weapons.get(choice);`
What is `weapon` here?
I received the following error: 
Error:(65, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable weapon
  location: class com.company.Main

Comment: Sorry, forgot the declaration. It is of class Weapon. (Fixed it in the code too so it should be compiling.)